# Expressing a value in polar and cartesian coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, polar-coordinates

I have to express the value of $\sqrt{i}$ in polar and cartesian form. I really don't know where to start this problem, any hint could help me please!

Answer (score 0):

*Here's a hint:* $$e^{\pi/2}=i$$

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can aproach this.

1) Set $a+ib=\sqrt{i}$, square both sides and solve for $a$ and $b$

2) Set $re^{i\theta}=\sqrt{i}$, again square both sides but this time solve for $r$ and $\theta$

---

**NOTE**: In both methods you will be equating the real and imaginary parts of the left-hand-side and right-hand-side of the resulting equations.